# How to display values in matrix as colors?

Tags: matlab

I've got a matrix A in MATLAB with the two values '100' and 'NaN' (the matrix below is just a simplified version of the original one). How can I display the values as black and white: for example '100' should appear as a black square and 'NaN' as a white square

```
A = [NaN NaN NaN 100 100; NaN NaN NaN 100 NaN; 100 NaN 100 NaN NaN];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just display the result of `isnan`. This will yield a `true` (white) value for all NaN's and `false` (black) for all non-NaN's.

```
imshow(isnan(A));
```

If you don't have the Image Processing Toolbox you can use `imagesc` instead

```
imagesc(isnan(A));
colormap gray
axis image
```

Comment: @EnzoBruckmamaan If this worked for you, consider marking it as a solution.